# Canvas draw rought circle for palette

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, palette

Hello i draw circle color palette using canvas, but problem is have seem bad pixels. Rought circle

[image]
[image]

How i can fix it?

code `jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/La5d6z07/`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'bad pixels'?

Comment: @Vadim: the circle isn't smooth, it's pixelated

Comment: i mean it's pixelated circle is not smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `canvas` element twice the size and force it with css to be half of it's width & height (=original size) in pixels.

This will make the image look great on retina screens and will apply browser's own smoothing when scaled to normal screens.